# showInputDialog - cancel option clicked

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, joptionpane

how to handle if the user clicks Cancel on inputDialog? I have tried previously posted solutions but neither did work.

here is my code

```
String bidString = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Place your bid ", "Bid",
                JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE);

    while(bidString.isEmpty())
    {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"You must enter a value",
                    "The Numbers Game", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);

        bidString = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "How much do you wish to bid?", "Initial funds"
                ,JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE);

        if(bidString != null)
        {
            return;
        }

    }
    int bid = Integer.parseInt(bidString);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try it like this:

```
String bidString;
while (true) {
    bidString = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Place your bid ", "Bid",
            JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE);
    if (bidString == null) {
        System.out.println("cancelled");
        break;
    }
    if (bidString.isEmpty()) {
        System.out.println("wrong entry");
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "You must enter a value",
                "The Numbers Game", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
        continue;
    }else{
        try {
            int bid = Integer.parseInt(bidString);
        } catch (NumberFormatException nfe) {
            System.out.println("no number entered");
            continue;
        }
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: The code is definitely working..please be more specific what is not working?

Comment: If(bidString == null)